# Strip special characters in span

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have a node like this in an XML file that I transform with XSLT 2.0:

```
<h2><span class='sun'>☼☼</span> my text (G1.2)</h2>
```

which includes some HTML special characters, as you see.

Now I need to generate XHTML like this:

```
<a href="....">my text</a>
```

So I have to strip out the span and the stuff between () and use the rest to generate the h2 header.
To strip the (), I have this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(replace( . ,'\([^\)]*\)'  ,''))"/>
```

which works OK. But to strip the span, I cannot use

```
<xsl:template match="span[@class='sun']"/>
```

Because I do not apply templates after the xsl:value-of anymore. So the span-template is never applied.

Can I strip the span in the same line? If not, how can I strip the span also?
Or can I replace the special characters in the  same replace function somehow? Then I would be left with an empty span element, but that's not a problem.

Comment: Can you show a little bit more of your XSLT? In particular, is you current **xsl:value-of** statement within a template that matches **h2**? Thank you!

Comment: You *can* use `<xsl:template match="span[@class='sun']"/>` if you call the contents of `<h1>` using `<xsl:apply-templates/>`. You can apply your expression to the `text()` children of `<h2>` which will not affect the `<span>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match the `child::text()` contents of `<h1>` separately from the `child::span` elements. This should work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="span[@class='sun']"/>

    <xsl:template match="h2/text()">
        <a href="">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(replace( . ,'\([^\)]*\)'  ,''))"/>
        </a>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I found this: <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(replace(replace( string-join(node(),'') , '[☼*]' ,'') ,'\([^\)]*\)' ,''))"/>

Comment: But if you can simply remove the span, that wouldn't be necessary. The stylesheet I posted is exactly what you are doing. The only difference is that I am matching `h2/text()` (the text *children* of `h2`) and not the entire `h2` node. With that, you can easily remove the `span`, since the default implicit templates will find it.

Comment: I understand. My solution is a bit ugly. I'll try yours. Thanks so far.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the template thus far. It (toct) generates a table of contents  from a HTML h1/h2/h3 structure recursively.
It is applied like this:

```
<xsl:call-template name="toct">
    <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="document(file)//(h1|h2|h3)"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="file" select="replace (file,'xml', 'xhtml')"/>
</xsl:call-template>


<xsl:template name="toct">
    <xsl:param name="nodes"/>
    <xsl:param name="file"/>
    <xsl:if test="count($nodes) > 0">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$nodes" group-starting-with="*[local-name() = name($nodes[1])]">
            <li>
                <!-- do not include empty header tags in the TOC -->
                <a>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="text()">
                            <xsl:if test="name($nodes[1])='h1'">
                                <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="$nodes[1]/@id"/></xsl:attribute>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="$file"/>#<xsl:value-of select="@id"/></xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(replace(replace( string-join(node(),'') , '[☼*]' ,'') ,'\([^\)]*\)' ,''))"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:attribute name="class">invisible</xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </a>
                <xsl:if test="current-group()[2]">
                    <ol>
                        <xsl:call-template name="toct">
                            <!-- strip the first node in the list. This is why you can use $nodes[1] to find out
                                which level of <h_> tags you are at -->
                            <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="current-group() except ."/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="file" select="$file"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </ol>
                </xsl:if>
            </li>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```